# Javascript compare string in an array

Tags: php, javascript, api, linkedin-api

```
function getPublicLink() {
   var div = document.getElementById('links'); // anchor tag
   var url;

   for(var x in div){
      url += div[x].href;
   }
}
```

This is for getting the list. My Problem is that I want to compare it with the json results below. If there is a matched. I will alter the anchor tag to remove the href attribute or make the text Connected ( Now it is "Invited"). The Linkedin connection code is:

```
function displayConnections(connections) {
   var members = connections.values;
   var publicUrl;

   for(var member in members) {
       publicUrl += members[member].publicProfileUrl;
   }
}
```

My problem is they are in a big string. What i want is to compare them one by one. I'm out of ideas since I'm just a JS beginner. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer.

```
for(var i in publicUrl) {
    for(var j in url) {
       if(url[j] === publicUrl[i]) {
          alert("Found " + url[j]);
       }
    }
}
```